# Read csv files recursively in all sub folders from a GCP bucket using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to load all csv files *recursively* from all sub folders available in a GCP bucket using python pandas.

Currently I am using **dask** to load data, but its very slow.

```
import dask
path = "gs://mybucket/parent_path + "*/*.csv"
getAllDaysData = dask.dataframe.read_csv(path).compute()
```

Can someone help me with better way.

Comment: Are you free in the solution to choose with `Python` ?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading into parquet files instead.
And use `pd.read_parquet(file, engine = 'pyarrow')` to convert it into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you might want to consider loading data into BigQuery first.
You can do something like this, as long as all csv-files have the some structure.

```
uri = f"gs://mybucket/parent_path/*.csv"
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
)

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    'destination_table',
    job_config=job_config,
    location=GCP_LOCATION
)
load_job_result = load_job.result()
```